# Subtract or add datetime fields which are returned from djangomodel

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-views

After searching, I could not find an answer to my problem. I have this model:

```
  class Subtask(models.Model):
    Created_subtask_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    subflag = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Created_subtask_date)
```

As you can see this object returns a string which is the created date of the subtask.

My problem is how can I substract or add two objects (two datetimes) of this model. For example if I have subtask1 which is equal with the date of this task. Then I have another object (eg subask 2) which has another date. I tried to convert them to integer but with no success.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Why convert them to integers? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to find the time difference between two objects.The datetimes in that type are strings. I tried to change `str(self.Created_subtask_date)` with `int(self.Created_subtask_date)` but of course I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the time difference then you should do it that way:

```
from datetime import timedelta    

date1 = subtask1.Created_subtask_date
date2 = subtask2.Created_subtask_date

diff = date1 - date2

print(type(diff))  # <class 'datetime.timedelta'>

print(diff.seconds)
print(diff.days)
```

More on [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert them to Integers.. You can get difference of two dates easily. for e.g

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime(2017,3,17,12,50,59)
d2 = datetime.now()

e = d2 - d
print(e.days,e.seconds) # output 3 (days) 41569 (seconds)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It seems great